# Using FBJS to change CSS

Tags: javascript, css, facebook, fbjs

I'm a bit stumped by the Facebook implementation of Javascript. I want to set up a listener on a checkbox so that when checked, it changes the class of an element I can get by ID.

I've been using the test console and have tried various permutations. Javascript is NOT my first language, nor my second, third... COuld anyone help me by translating my pseudocode?

```
<input class="one" type="checkbox" onclick="setcolor(this.checkedornot)">
    function setcolor(checkedornot){
        if checkedornot == true {set p.one to p.one.GREEN}
        if checkedornot == false {set p.one to p.one.RED}
    }
```

Obviously this is not javascript, but that is how I can best explain the functionality I need. In my short tests, FBJS doesn't even seem to register onClick events. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

FBJS has its own getters and setters. Getting "checked" and setting/removing classes are different. And, you would have to remove the `red` class if you are adding the `green` class and visa versa. Or, if you just want to overwrite all the classes of the element, you can use the `setClassName(class)` method instead, I'm going to use the `add`/`remove` class methods in my answer since it is less destructive.

[FBJS Docs: Manipulating Objects](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBJS#Manipulating_Objects)

For the `onclick` event, I think you're supposed to use the `addEventListener` if `onclick` doesn't work. [Events in FBJS](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBJS#Events)

Instead of `this.checked`, FBJS uses `getChecked`. So when you add the event listener (for `click`), add a `this.getChecked()` for the `arg`.

```
setColor(this.getChecked());
```

And for the function:

```
function setColor (isChecked) {
    var p = document.getElementById(ID-OF-P);
    if (isChecked) {
        p.removeClassName("red");
        p.addClassName("green");
    } else {
        p.removeClassName("green");
        p.addClassName("red");
    }
}
```

I am a JS newb too though. I **think** this is right.

Comment: Close kmiyashiro, you need this.getChecked().  It's a function, not an attribute, so you need to call it.  You're correct about FBJS and it's custom methods though.

Comment: ah, I KNEW it. I even thought about adding it but I wasn't completely sure. Thanks, I changed it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the onclick event you need to use...

```
this.checked
```

Then your function will look like this:

```
var setColor = function(isChecked) {
    var myElement = document.getElementById("one");
    if (isChecked) {
        myElement.className = "myGreenClass";
    } else {
        myElement.className = "myRedClass";
    }
};
```

Comment: FBJS has different getters and setters than normal JS syntax. Check out http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBJS

Answer (score 0):

kmiyashiro is mostly right except for the getters and setters for the class name
it should be

```
  if (isChecked) {
    p.setClassName("green");
} else {
    p.setClassName("red");
}
```

Since its just a set meothod and there are no remove methods, you don't need to worry about removiing the class name, it will just get overwritten.

check out this list for more getters and setters
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/FBJS#Manipulating_Objects